# JPA find the top data of orderById and filtered the Id by string

Tags: java, spring-boot

i try to find the top data of orderById and filtered the Id with 'like' by string.. 
i have **findFirstByOrderByOrderIdDesc()** to find top data with orderBy and **findByOrderIdStartsWith(String orderPrefix);** to filter data with 'like' clause..

so, in interface i try to combine them like this :

**findFirstByOrderIdStartsWithByOrderIdDesc(String orderPrefix)** unfortunately, still got 'No property startsWithByIdDesc found'

my entity:

```
@Id
@Column(name="order_id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
private String orderId; 

private String orderPrefix;
```

appreciate, for any good suggestion for my problem's

Comment: `findFirstByOrderIdStartsWithByOrderIdDesc` change to `findFirstByOrderIdStartsWithOrderByIdDesc`

Comment: thx @dmtr it works with findFirstByOrderIdStartsWithOrderByOrderIdDesc